# Background Color on FloatingActionButton

Tags: flutter, colors, background-color, floating-action-button

I know there should be a neater way to code this than manually adding the class getKey() for every single iteration. However, whenever I run this code, I get all black rectangles. How do I go about getting the colors I input within the getKey() function? It's suppose to look like a xylophone on the phone at execution.

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(XylophoneApp());

class XylophoneApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // void playSound() {
  //   final player = AudioCache();
  //   player.play('note$n.wav');
  // }

  Expanded buildKey({int n, backgroundColors: Color}) {
    return Expanded(
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          final player = AudioCache();
          player.play('note$n.wav');
        },
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                buildKey(n: 1, backgroundColors: Colors.red),
                buildKey(n: 2, backgroundColors: Colors.orange),
                buildKey(n: 3, backgroundColors: Colors.yellow),
                buildKey(n: 4, backgroundColors: Colors.green),
                buildKey(n: 5, backgroundColors: Colors.teal),
                buildKey(n: 6, backgroundColors: Colors.blue),
                buildKey(n: 7, backgroundColors: Colors.purple),
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is because your not using `backgroundColors` and also you are missing child widget, try changing to this:

```
Expanded buildKey({int n, backgroundColors: Color}) {
    return Expanded(
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: backgroundColors,
        onPressed: () {
          final player = AudioCache();
          player.play('note$n.wav');
        },
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Edit 1

If you just want a rectanble with color try using GestureDetector and Container widget like this:

```
Expanded buildKey({int n, backgroundColors: Color}) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
          final player = AudioCache();
          player.play('note$n.wav');
       },
       child: Container(
          color: backgroundColors,
       ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I'm trying to do it without the "add" or any other symbol on top. Just a rectangle key the width of the screen for each getKey() for each varying color. So at the end it looks like a xylophone

Comment: Thank you so very much. I have gone ahead and used it and it worked! The only thing I had to change was Icon(Icons.add) to Icon(null)

Comment: Nice, but check the Edit, and if it works please mark as good answer :D

Answer (score 0):

try below answer

```
FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      // Add your onPressed code here
    },
    child: const Icon(Icons.add),
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,//change backgroundColor your needs
  ),
```

your screen  ->  [image: scrrenshot]

Comment: I'm trying to do it without the "add" or any other symbol on top. Just a rectangle key the width of the screen for each getKey() for each varying color. So at the end it looks like a xylophone